# Android : how to compile java code to class

Tags: java, android

am trying to compile java code to class

i tried  `javac dumy_class.java`

which give me error

```
error: package android.util does not exist
```

i know that package is inside android.jar

path to my android sdk is :

> C:\Program
>   Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar

and my java file path is :

> C:\dumy_class.java

so please how can i compile so that i get class ...... after that my target is to get dex file

so please help

thanks

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Use the android gradle build tools. It is much easier and designed for the task: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: i think gradle is for android studio to compile entire project , i just want to convert mycode.java to mycode.class then i will convert into dex so that i can dynamically load this dex file in my app

Comment: The android gradle build system is independent of AndroidStudio. It can and should be used stand alone as well.

Comment: Yes. See here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basic-Project

Comment: finally i create lib project and create .arr lib as output ..... so now how i can dynamically load .arr lib and access classes inside my app

Comment: You reference the library project from your main project. See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide